# PHP Undefined Index warnings when updating Drupal

Tags: drupal

I am running the latest CiviCRM with Drupal 7 (latest and all modules up to date). When I run Drupal database updates, such as when updating a module, I get the following errors:

```
Notice: Undefined index: admin/structure/types/manage/civicrm_activity/fields in civicrm_entity_menu_alter() (line 23 of /home/mysite/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm_entity/civicrm_entity.module).
Notice: Undefined index: admin/structure/types/manage/civicrm_action_schedule/fields in civicrm_entity_menu_alter() (line 23 of /home/mysite/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm_entity/civicrm_entity.module).
Notice: Undefined index: admin/structure/types/manage/civicrm_address/fields in civicrm_entity_menu_alter() (line 23 of /home/mysite/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm_entity/civicrm_entity.module).
Notice: Undefined index: admin/structure/types/manage/civicrm_campaign/fields in civicrm_entity_menu_alter() (line 23 of /home/mysite/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm_entity/civicrm_entity.module).
Notice: Undefined index: admin/structure/types/manage/civicrm_contact/fields in civicrm_entity_menu_alter() (line 23 of /home/mysite/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm_entity/civicrm_entity.module).
Notice: Undefined index: admin/structure/types/manage/civicrm_contribution/fields in civicrm_entity_menu_alter() (line 23 of /home/mysite/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm_entity/civicrm_entity.module).
Notice: Undefined index: admin/structure/types/manage/civicrm_contribution_page/fields in civicrm_entity_menu_alter() (line 23 of /home/mysite/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm_entity/civicrm_entity.module).
Notice: Undefined index: admin/structure/types/manage/civicrm_email/fields in civicrm_entity_menu_alter() (line 23 of /home/mysite/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm_entity/civicrm_entity.module).
Notice: Undefined index: admin/structure/types/manage/civicrm_entity_tag/fields in civicrm_entity_menu_alter() (line 23 of /home/mysite/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm_entity/civicrm_entity.module).
Notice: Undefined index: admin/structure/types/manage/civicrm_financial_type/fields in civicrm_entity_menu_alter() (line 23 of /home/mysite/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm_entity/civicrm_entity.module).
Notice: Undefined index: admin/structure/types/manage/civicrm_event/fields in civicrm_entity_menu_alter() (line 23 of /home/mysite/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm_entity/civicrm_entity.module).
Notice: Undefined index: admin/structure/types/manage/civicrm_group/fields in civicrm_entity_menu_alter() (line 23 of /home/mysite/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm_entity/civicrm_entity.module).
Notice: Undefined index: admin/structure/types/manage/civicrm_grant/fields in civicrm_entity_menu_alter() (line 23 of /home/mysite/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm_entity/civicrm_entity.module).
Notice: Undefined index: admin/structure/types/manage/civicrm_membership/fields in civicrm_entity_menu_alter() (line 23 of /home/mysite/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm_entity/civicrm_entity.module).
Notice: Undefined index: admin/structure/types/manage/civicrm_membership_type/fields in civicrm_entity_menu_alter() (line 23 of /home/mysite/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm_entity/civicrm_entity.module).
Notice: Undefined index: admin/structure/types/manage/civicrm_participant/fields in civicrm_entity_menu_alter() (line 23 of /home/mysite/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm_entity/civicrm_entity.module).
Notice: Undefined index: admin/structure/types/manage/civicrm_phone/fields in civicrm_entity_menu_alter() (line 23 of /home/mysite/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm_entity/civicrm_entity.module).
Notice: Undefined index: admin/structure/types/manage/civicrm_price_set/fields in civicrm_entity_menu_alter() (line 23 of /home/mysite/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm_entity/civicrm_entity.module).
Notice: Undefined index: admin/structure/types/manage/civicrm_price_field/fields in civicrm_entity_menu_alter() (line 23 of /home/mysite/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm_entity/civicrm_entity.module).
Notice: Undefined index: admin/structure/types/manage/civicrm_price_field_value/fields in civicrm_entity_menu_alter() (line 23 of /home/mysite/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm_entity/civicrm_entity.module).
Notice: Undefined index: admin/structure/types/manage/civicrm_relationship/fields in civicrm_entity_menu_alter() (line 23 of /home/mysite/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm_entity/civicrm_entity.module).
Notice: Undefined index: admin/structure/types/manage/civicrm_relationship_type/fields in civicrm_entity_menu_alter() (line 23 of /home/mysite/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm_entity/civicrm_entity.module).
Notice: Undefined index: admin/structure/types/manage/civicrm_tag/fields in civicrm_entity_menu_alter() (line 23 of /home/mysite/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm_entity/civicrm_entity.module).
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Just happened here. Can you tell me if, after all these notices, civicrm is still functioning ok ?

Comment: It seems to be, but I am still getting them.

Comment: It would happen every time the menu is rebuilt. Take a look here https://www.drupal.org/node/2564757

Answer (score 2):

I think this is some issues with [civicrm entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/civicrm_entity)
module.

Comment: This looks correct to me - recorded to the [CiviCRM Entity issue queue](https://www.drupal.org/project/civicrm_entity) @ https://www.drupal.org/node/2564757 - would be good if you can add further detail there to help track down why it happens. (Haven't observed it myself.)

Comment: Thanks for doing that. It looks like someone there understands the issue at least.